# Android Studio layout references losing effect when tab is reopened

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

On `Android Studio 3.0` I have a `layout.xml` resource for a layout. Its dimensions, text/hint and other attributes aren't hard coded (like having `android:width="2dp"`, but instead all referencing `dim.xml` and `strings.xml` - as it is advised on google.developers (like `android:width="@dim/width"`.

However, every time I either reopen Android Studio or the respective `layout.xml` tab my `@dim/dimensions` or `@strings/strings` references disappear and give room to the originals `2dp` or `text` respectively. Then I have to hover and click each of those items to the reference suggestion. If the tab is closed and reopened I need to do everything again...

Is this a bug from the IDE, and is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a feature of Android Studio, but you can turn it off. It's not actually *replacing* your resource references with hardcoded values; it's showing you what the resources actually map to.

To turn it off, uncheck this option (Editor > General > Code Folding > Android String References):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio shows the values of these references and the color is gray by default but these actually are references, you don't need to worry about that.^_^
just like this:
[reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6cTI.png)